# Device info wp7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, device

Im trying to retrieve some device information programmatically so I found something I need using DeviceStatus (DeviceExtendedProperties same thing) and Environment classes.

Is it everything? I would like to get more info, for example memory("hard disk") total / empty space, or cpu frequency , screen dpi..etc..

In Settings > info on every wp7 device I get more information as software/hardware revision, hardware/software radio version, bootloader version and processor version as well.

Hope it's possible to get more stuff!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no other info available. For available free space you can use IsolatedStorageFile's properties (AvailableFreeSpace)

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.availablefreespace(v=vs.95).aspx

nothing else is accessible (apart from Device Extended Properties).

Comment: mmm, well http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.phone.info.deviceextendedproperties(v=vs.92).aspx Im retrieving the properties from DeviceStatus... Thank you!!!